# Should my sitemap and robots.txt have http or https urls for the given scenario

Tags: https, sitemap, robots.txt, nginx

- My website is running on node.js and runs in http on port 3000
- I am using NGINX to enable https access so that all pages are served as https
- I have placed my sitemap.xml and robots.txt inside the public folder of my express app
- Should the URL's inside be http or https. They say you should not have both in the same file
- Nginx I assume redirects HTTP traffic to HTTPS

Can someone kindly suggest?

Comment: You don't tell the pieces that are actually relevant.   Do HTTP and HTTPS both work and show the same content?  Does one redirect to the other?

Comment: Sorry, I enabled nginx such that all http requests are turned into https, there is no http to anything on the website